# Ponteiros Inteligentes: com ou sem make_unique<>

Tags: c++, c++14

Vi alguns vídeos sobre ponteiros inteligentes e notei diferentes declarações dos demais.

Nesse primeiro caso, o ponteiro é declarado diretamente como um novo objeto:

```
unique_ptr<player>p1(new player);
```

No segundo, é declarado um ponteiro por meio do método make.

```
unique_ptr<player>p2 = make_unique<player>();
```

Gostaria de saber qual seria a diferença entre estes dois tipos de declaração e qual seria o mais propício ao uso e por qual motivo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514509/advantages-of-using-stdmake-unique-over-new-operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os **ponteiro inteligente** descreve uma classe de ponteiros  que adicionam funcionalidades extras em relação aos ponteiros convencionais. Essas funcionalidades incluem recursos de gerenciamento automático de memória que preveni vazamentos de memória.

No primeiro exemplo citado na perguta, o objeto é criado usando o operador new e  passado para o construtor do `unique_ptr`. A vantagem do uso do **unique_ptr**  gerencia automaticamente a memória aloca  o objeto e o destroi quando sai do escopo. um ponto importante pois não precisa gerenciar manualmente a alocação e desalocação de memória.

No segundo exemplo, é usado o método utilitário `make_unique`, que cria um objeto dinamicamente e retorna `unique_ptr` que o gerencia. Fazendo com que a criação de objetos gerenciados por ponteiros inteligentes sejam mais fáceis e menos propenso a erros do que usar o operador `new`

O detalhe  do `make_unique` é a garantia de que o objeto vai ser construído em uma única etapa e a alocação de memória vai ser feita com segurança.

cria um objeto com o operador new e passa para o construtor do [**unique_ptr**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

```
unique_ptr<player>p1(new player);
```

É uma função utilitária [**make_unique**](https://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique.html) para cria e gerenciar automaticamente um objeto.

```
unique_ptr<player>p2 = make_unique<player>();
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, sua resposta foi 10